# trying to update my project to ios 7 error - drawInRect deprected

Tags: xcode4, ios7

I am trying to update my app to work on IOS 7 and get an error telling me the following code is deprecated and to use with attributes. The Apple developer site just says its deprecated but doesnt give a clue how to fix it.  Can anyone please translate my code into whatever the new format is?

```
[str drawInRect: r
       withFont: f1
  lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
      alignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: Have you tried `drawInRect:withAttributes:`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[str drawInRect:rect withAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: f1,
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
NSString *font = @"Courier-Bold";
  #ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                                                       NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle }];
    #else
    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    #endif
```

While textToDraw is string that you want to draw. I hope it helps.